# Deleting an existing file in java and renaming the temp file

Tags: java

I want to read an existing file and write the file contents to another temp file without a particular line...
  i could not able to delete the existing file and renaming the temp file...

```
File tf = new File("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\temp.tmp");

       FileReader fr = new     FileReader("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\Employee_info.txt");
       BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(fr);

       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tf);
       PrintWriter bw =new PrintWriter(fw);
       String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            if(line.contains(del_id)) continue;

            bw.println(line);

        }

        bw.close();
        fw.close();
        br.close();
        fr.close();
        File real =new File("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\Employee_info.txt");
        real.delete();
        tf.renameTo(real);
```

Comment: You should certainly _br.close()_ *before* trying to _real.delete()_

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File) - renameTo(File) might not work and from my experience it doesn't.  You could use Runtime.getRuntime().exec().  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127511/running-a-command-line-operation-from-within-java

Comment: i did that....but still it is not working...

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times. You can simply edit it to improve it and get more visibility.